# Passing 'navigation' AND 'props' to child components

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation

Normally with navigation you receive the props on child component like this, with the curly braces:

```
const MatchHistoryScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
```

But I believe props you do without the curly braces, like this:

```
const MatchToggleComponent = (props) => {
```

So how do you combine both 'navigation' and 'props' for a child component? Putting 'props' in curly braces did not work for me. I think a potential use case for this is if you are passing down props from App.js together with your navigation prop.

Comment: Did you try logging props? Cause the "curly braces" that you say is just destructuring, so you should have the navigation inside the props object too. So just do `(props)` and try to see all of the properties you have.

Comment: Oh yeah I see that works! So you can do like props.navigation and prop.route. The 'destructuring' you mentioned: why do you write it with the curly braces for navigation and route but the 'props' is not with curly braces? Is it because 'props' is top in the hierarchy and everything else falls underneath it, and by specifying { navigation, route } means you automatically target the same-named props.navigation and props.route?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `props` object is what a component receives from React depending on how you have configured your app. If you have Redux, then you are going to receive some props from there. If the component is a child, and you are passing some properties from the parent, you are going to receive props from the father too. If the parent is passing navigation, then you will have it as props in your child.

`props` is just an object that a component receives from multiple sources. It can actually be called anything, `banana` or `sporp`, it's just a convention to call that object `props`.

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on the other hand is used to "unpack" properties of an object (or values from an array) into separate variables. So when you are unpacking the navigation properties, you are essentially going from

```
const MatchToggleComponent = (props) => {
// props object contains navigation and route properties, which can be accessed as props.navigation and props.route
```

into

```
const MatchToggleComponent = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    // you unpack navigation and route properties into separate variables `navigation` and `route`, ready to be used in your component.
```

Imagine that the parent of MatchToggleComponent looks like

```
return (
  <>
    <MatchToggleComponent
      foo={bar}
      one={two}
    />
  </>
)
```

So your `props` object is going to have the `foo` property, `one` property, and then `navigation` property and `route` property. Destructuring effectively let's you pick the properties that interest you and "unpack" them, ready to be used inside your component without referencing the `props` object all the time.

So if you wanted to use `foo` prop, AND your navigation props, you would do

```
const MatchToggleComponent = ({ foo, navigation, route }) => {
```

You could do that in any component, just try it out.

If you have any additional questions please don't hesitate to continue the discussion :)

Edit 1:

`req.query` seems to be an object with properties `userId` and `activeMethods`. When you destructure the object, you should be using curly braces. Consequently, when you destructure arrays, you should be using square brackets `[]`.
The variable names that you destructure should be called the same as in the objects. For example:

```
const foo = {
  some: ...,
  other: ...,
  last: ...,
};
```

If you do `const { bar } = foo`, then JS is not going to know that you want to get the first prop of the object and this will throw an error. So the variable you create should match the prop name in the object, like

```
const { last, other } = foo;
```

As you can see, the order doesn't really matter (the situation is a bit different with arrays, but I won't be covering this here).

What you can do is that you can rename the variable WHILE destructuring properties from the object. Imagine you want to get the `last` prop from the `foo` object, but you want it named `first` for some reason. Then you would do

```
const { last: first } = foo;
```

This will effectively unpack the `last` prop from the `foo` object for you and rename it into first, so you'll be able to use `const first` across your code.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin! Regarding destructuring: let's say my app.get destructures 2 variables using curly braces in the following way:
  var { userId, activeMatchIds } = req.query; Do the variable names 'userId' and 'activeMatchIds' have to be equal to the variables names in req.query? Or does it just automatically take number 1 and 2 from there? And, why is it done with curly braces here?

Comment: @beyondtdr added info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using useNavigation hook which gives access to navigation object.

example:

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: useNavigation returns the navigation prop of the screen it's inside. Screens declared in App.js are not inside any screens; they are the screens themselves.